# How to get a clicked button id from QButtonGroup in qt 6.4 through signal and slot connection

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt6, qbuttongroup

i am new to qt and what to know how to get the id of the button that is clicked in qt through signal and slot.

connect(group, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(int)), this, SLOT(buttonWasClicked(int)));

This was the earlier syntax to get the id, but qt has declared buttonClicked(int) as obsolete and it no longer allows us use it. is there any new replacement for this code.

Plz forgive if this question was silly, but i don't know much about qt yet.

Comment: Where did you read that [`QButtonGroup::buttonClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbuttongroup.html#buttonClicked) was obsolete?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup-obsolete.html    in this link

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post.  `buttonClicked(int)` is obsolete but `buttonClicked(QAbstractButton *)` is provided instead.  Will that not suffice?

Comment: But can we get clicked button id with buttonClicked(QAbstractButton *)? if yes, how?

Comment: Then simply look around in the documentation: [QButtonGroup::idClicked(int)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbuttongroup.html#idClicked)

Comment: @chehrlic +1 I should probably heed your advice as well: I missed that one :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QButtonGroup::buttonClicked(int)` signal is obsoleted but you can still use [`QButtonGroup:: buttonClicked(QAbstractButton *)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbuttongroup.html#buttonClicked).  Perhaps use it in conjunction with a lambda and your existing `buttonWasClicked` slot...

```
connect(group, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked,
        [this, group](QAbstractButton *button)
          {
            buttonWasClicked(group->id(button));
          });
```

Alternatively, use the [`idClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbuttongroup.html#idClicked) signal as suggested by @chehrlic...

```
connect(group, &QButtonGroup::idClicked, this, &MainWindow::buttonWasClicked);
```

(Assuming `MainWindow` is the type pointed to by `this`.)

Comment: but it gives me an error in line 2: [this,group] saying that ' mainwindow.cpp:342:22: 'group' in capture list does not name a variable '.

Comment: can you do this without lambda function?

Comment: @2004satwik I captured `group` in the lambda because that's the variable name you'd used in the question -- you should pass a pointer to the `QGroupBox` you're using.

Comment: great, the idClicked signal worked !

Comment: However, removing 'group' from [this, group] also worked for me, though doing so doesn't make it a lambda function. Btw i don't know much about lambda function either ;)